# A Desktop App in Java using Facebook API (java.net.UnknownHost Exception)

Tags: java, facebook, api

I am trying to build a desktop app in java using facebook API provided by google. I have a number of questions :

1) Do I have to make use of socket programming? (coz I am a newbie and I haven't :/ )

2) And it is giving a java.net.UnknownHost Exception in facebook api when I try to create a auth_token.

Any extra info would be a great help. :)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.facebook.com
at com.google.code.facebookapi.BasicClientHelper.runtimeException(BasicClientHelper.java:123)
at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.callMethod(ExtensibleClient.java:538)
at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.callMethod(ExtensibleClient.java:446)
at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.auth_createToken(ExtensibleClient.java:860)
at com.google.code.facebookapi.SpecificReturnTypeAdapter.auth_createToken(SpecificReturnTypeAdapter.java:73)
at facebookConnection.FbStartingPoint.<init>(FbStartingPoint.java:26)
at sourcepoint.FirstWindow$1.actionPerformed(FirstWindow.java:41)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.facebook.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.postRequest(ExtensibleClient.java:583)
at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.callMethod(ExtensibleClient.java:534)
... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It sound like your machine can't access `api.facebook.com` host. Are you using a proxy to connect to Internet?

Try using telnet to make sure the whole computer can connect to the internet (not only your proxy-configured driver):

```
> telnet api.facebook.com 80
Trying 66.220.149.99...
Connected to api.facebook.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 16:29:53 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 134

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Method Not Implemented</H1>
Invalid method in request<P>
</BODY></HTML>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: yaa i am behind my college proxy with LDAP id and password

Comment: @Scoop: that's your problem. You will need to setup Facebook API to use the PROXY connection (with LDAP ID/PASSWORD and everything).

Answer (score 0):

`api.facebook.com` is the endpoint for the old REST API which is deprecated; you should probably be connecting to `graph.facebook.com`

Nonetheless, api.facebook.com should be resolvable and still work if you're using the legacy APIs.

This is almost certainly a problem with your network, firewall, computer, DNS, or JDK - its a problem with your code connecting to Facebook, not a problem on Facebook's side

Comment: I am behind a proxy server with a username password. What modifications do I have to make in my code then. And do I have to use socket programming??

Comment: though I setup the proxy in Java, the error still persists :/